# A module to make JSON in Python easier

Tags: python, performance, object-oriented, library

I recently wrote the [livejson](https://github.com/controversial/livejson) module as a way to make working with JSON in Python easier. The idea of the module is that you initialize a `livejson.File`, and then you can interact with your JSON file with the same interface as a Python `dict`, except your changes are reflected in the file in realtime.

I'd like to know how I can improve this.

- Is my design good, in terms of things like naming, OOP design, etc.?
- Are there ways I could improve performance *without* decreasing reliability? I implemented the context manager with a concept of "grouped writes" specifically so that repetitive operations could achieve the performance of the native objects.
- Should I be concerned about thread safety?

## The code

Here's the code. I've tried to document it well with comments and docstrings, and also tried to follow [PEP8](http://pep8.org) so I hope it's readable:

---

Imports:

```
"""A module implementing a pseudo-dict class which is bound to a JSON file.

As you change the contents of the dict, the JSON file will be updated in
real-time. Magic.
"""

import collections
import os
import json
```

The code begins with some helper functions and generic base classes:

```
# MISC HELPERS


def _initfile(path, data="dict"):
    """Initialize an empty JSON file."""
    data = {} if data.lower() == "dict" else []
    # The file will need to be created if it doesn't exist
    if not os.path.exists(path):  # The file doesn't exist
        # Raise exception if the directory that should contain the file doesn't
        # exist
        dirname = os.path.dirname(path)
        if dirname and not os.path.exists(dirname):
            raise IOError(
                ("Could not initialize empty JSON file in non-existant "
                 "directory '{}'").format(os.path.dirname(path))
            )
        # Write an empty file there
        with open(path, "w") as f:
            json.dump(data, f)
        return True
    elif len(open(path, "r").read()) == 0:  # The file is empty
        with open(path, "w") as f:
            json.dump(data, f)
    else:  # The file exists and contains content
        return False


class _ObjectBase(object):
    """Class inherited by most things.

    Implements the lowest common denominator for all emulating classes.
    """
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        out = self.data[key]

        # Nesting
        if isinstance(out, (list, dict)):
            # If it's the top level, we can use [] for the path
            pathInData = self.pathInData if hasattr(self, "pathInData") else []
            newPathInData = pathInData + [key]
            # The top level, i.e. the File class, not a nested class. If we're
            # already the top level, just use self.
            toplevel = self.base if hasattr(self, "base") else self
            nestClass = _NestedList if isinstance(out, list) else _NestedDict
            return nestClass(toplevel, newPathInData)
        # Not a list or a dict, don't worry about it
        else:
            return out

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data)

    # Methods not-required by the ABC

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.data)

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.data)

    # MISC
    def _checkType(self, key):
        """Make sure the type of a key is appropriate."""
        pass
```

One of the major challenges I faced was easily supporting nested JSON structures, with the easy syntax of `my_file["a"]["b"] = "c"`. It was difficult to make these cases behave properly because `__setitem__` is not called in this case. To overcome this, I set up simple "nesting" classes to replace Python `list`s and `dict`s in nested situations. These mainly just listen for `__setitem__` and tell the top-level class to update the file's contents.

```
# NESTING CLASSES


class _NestedBase(_ObjectBase):
    """Inherited by _NestedDict and _NestedList, implements methods common
    between them. Takes arguments 'fileobj' which specifies the parent File
    object, and 'pathToThis' which specifies where in the JSON file this object
    exists (as a list).
    """
    def __init__(self, fileobj, pathToThis):
        self.pathInData = pathToThis
        self.base = fileobj

    @property
    def data(self):
        # Start with the top-level data
        d = self.base.data
        # Navigate through the object to find where self.pathInData points
        for i in self.pathInData:
            d = d[i]
        # And return the result
        return d

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self._checkType(key)
        # Store the whole data
        data = self.base.data
        # Iterate through and find the right part of the data
        d = data
        for i in self.pathInData:
            d = d[i]
        # It is passed by reference, so modifying the found object modifies
        # the whole thing
        d[key] = value
        # Update the whole file with the modification
        self.base.set_data(data)

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        # See __setitem__ for details on how this works
        data = self.base.data
        d = data
        for i in self.pathInData:
            d = d[i]
        del d[key]
        self.base.set_data(data)


class _NestedDict(_NestedBase, collections.MutableMapping):
    """A pseudo-dict class to replace vanilla dicts inside a livejson.File.

    This "watches" for changes made to its content, then tells
    the base livejson.File instance to update itself so that the file always
    reflects the changes you've made.

    This class is what allows for nested calls like this

    >>> f = livejson.File("myfile.json")
    >>> f["a"]["b"]["c"] = "d"

    to update the file.
    """
    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.data)

    def _checkType(self, key):
        if not isinstance(key, str):
            raise TypeError("JSON only supports strings for keys, not '{}'. {}"
                            .format(type(key).__name__, "Try using a list for"
                                    " storing numeric keys" if
                                    isinstance(key, int) else ""))


class _NestedList(_NestedBase, collections.MutableSequence):
    """A pseudo-list class to replace vanilla lists inside a livejson.File.

    This "watches" for changes made to its content, then tells
    the base livejson.File instance to update itself so that the file always
    reflects the changes you've made.

    This class is what allows for nested calls involving lists like this:

    >>> f = livejson.File("myfile.json")
    >>> f["a"].append("foo")

    to update the file.
    """
    def insert(self, index, value):
        # See _NestedBase.__setitem__ for details on how this works
        data = self.base.data
        d = data
        for i in self.pathInData:
            d = d[i]
        d.insert(index, value)
        self.base.set_data(data)
```

Here we have the main element of the module, the classes which envelop everything else:

```
# THE MAIN CLASSES


class _BaseFile(_ObjectBase):
    """Class inherited by DictFile and ListFile.

    This implements all the required methods common between
    collections.MutableMapping and collections.MutableSequence."""
    def __init__(self, path, pretty=False, sort_keys=False):
        self.path = path
        self.path = path
        self.pretty = pretty
        self.sort_keys = sort_keys
        self.indent = 2  # Default indentation level

        _initfile(self.path,
                  "list" if isinstance(self, ListFile) else "dict")

    def _data(self):
        """A simpler version of data to avoid infinite recursion in some cases.

        Don't use this.
        """
        if self.is_caching:
            return self.cache
        with open(self.path, "r") as f:
            return json.load(f)

    @property
    def data(self):
        """Get a vanilla dict object to represent the file."""
        # Update type in case it's changed
        self._updateType()
        # And return
        return self._data()

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self._checkType(key)
        data = self.data
        data[key] = value
        self.set_data(data)

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        data = self.data
        del data[key]
        self.set_data(data)

    def _updateType(self):
        """Make sure that the class behaves like the data structure that it
        is, so that we don't get a ListFile trying to represent a dict."""
        data = self._data()
        # Change type if needed
        if isinstance(data, dict) and isinstance(self, ListFile):
            self.__class__ = DictFile
        elif isinstance(data, list) and isinstance(self, DictFile):
            self.__class__ = ListFile

    # Bonus features!

    def set_data(self, data):
        """Overwrite the file with new data. You probably shouldn't do
        this yourself, it's easy to screw up your whole file with this."""
        if self.is_caching:
            self.cache = data
        else:
            fcontents = self.file_contents
            with open(self.path, "w") as f:
                try:
                    # Write the file. Keep user settings about indentation, etc
                    indent = self.indent if self.pretty else None
                    json.dump(data, f, sort_keys=self.sort_keys, indent=indent)
                except Exception as e:
                    # Rollback to prevent data loss
                    f.seek(0)
                    f.truncate()
                    f.write(fcontents)
                    # And re-raise the exception
                    raise e
        self._updateType()

    def remove(self):
        """Delete the file from the disk completely."""
        os.remove(self.path)

    @property
    def file_contents(self):
        """Get the raw file contents of the file."""
        with open(self.path, "r") as f:
            return f.read()

    # Grouped writes

    @property
    def is_caching(self):
        """Returns a boolean value describing whether a grouped write is
        underway.
        """
        return hasattr(self, "cache")

    def __enter__(self):
        self.cache = self.data
        return self  # This enables using "as"

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        # We have to write manually here because __setitem__ is set up to write
        # to cache, not to file
        with open(self.path, "w") as f:
            json.dump(self.cache, f)
        del self.cache


class DictFile(_BaseFile, collections.MutableMapping):
    """A class emulating Python's dict that will update a JSON file as it is
    modified.
    """
    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.data)

    def _checkType(self, key):
        if not isinstance(key, str):
            raise TypeError("JSON only supports strings for keys, not '{}'. {}"
                            .format(type(key).__name__, "Try using a list for"
                                    " storing numeric keys" if
                                    isinstance(key, int) else ""))


class ListFile(_BaseFile, collections.MutableSequence):
    """A class emulating a Python list that will update a JSON file as it is
    modified. Use this class directly when creating a new file if you want the
    base object to be an array.
    """
    def insert(self, index, value):
        data = self.data
        data.insert(index, value)
        self.set_data(data)

    def clear(self):
        # Under Python 3, this method is already in place. I've implemented it
        # myself to maximize compatibility with Python 2. Note that the
        # docstring here is stolen from Python 3.
        """L.clear() -> None -- remove all items from L."""
        self.set_data([])
```

And finally, this is what a user will directly initialize (most of the time). `File` is a class so that I can have `staticmethod`s on it, but it really behaves like a factory function since it immediately changes `self.__class__`. Initializing a `File()` will give you either a `ListFile` or a `DictFile` object.

```
class File(object):
    """The main interface of livejson. Emulates a list or a dict, updating a
    JSON file in real-time as it is modified.

    This will be automatically replaced with either a ListFile or as
    DictFile based on the contents of your file (a DictFile is the default when
    creating a new file).
    """

    def __init__(self, path, pretty=False, sort_keys=True, indent=2):
        # When creating a blank JSON file, it's better to make the top-level an
        # Object ("dict" in Python), rather than an Array ("list" in python),
        # because that's the case for most JSON files.
        self.path = path
        self.pretty = pretty
        self.sort_keys = sort_keys
        self.indent = indent

        _initfile(self.path)

        with open(self.path, "r") as f:
            data = json.load(f)
        if isinstance(data, dict):
            self.__class__ = DictFile
        elif isinstance(data, list):
            self.__class__ = ListFile

    @staticmethod
    def with_data(path, data):
        """Initialize a new file that starts out with some data. Pass data
        as a list, dict, or JSON string.
        """
        # De-jsonize data if necessary
        if isinstance(data, str):
            data = json.loads(data)

        # Make sure this is really a new file
        if os.path.exists(path):
            raise ValueError("File exists, not overwriting data. Use "
                             "'set_data' if you really want to do this.")
        else:
            f = File(path)
            f.set_data(data)
            return f


# Aliases for backwards-compatibility
Database = File
ListDatabase = ListFile
DictDatabase = DictFile
```

## Usage

Here's example usage in case that's helpful to critique my API design:

Basic usage:

```
import livejson
f = livejson.File("test.json")
f["a"] = "b"
# That's it, the file has been written to!
```

Usage as a context manager:

```
import livejson
with livejson.File("test.json") as f:
    f["a"] = "b"
```

---

If I could get some feedback on this that would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a first look pretty clean code, and you also presented it in a nice
fashion, so off to a good start.

I'll go with your questions first:

- Naming looks mostly good, though I'd wager that at some point generic
  names with "Base" in it will make it harder to understand than
  necessary - unfortunately I don't have a good suggestion as to what
  other names would be more helpful.
- Any unspecific question about performance should get the answer "take
  a profiler and look" IMO.  Really, there's more to worry about than
  raw numbers, including the fact that this is Python.  For starts the
  regular `json` module also isn't the fastest.  However correctness
  comes first, so
- not only is thread safety a concern, access from multiple processes is
  a concern even more so.  The one pattern that should really be used
  here at least is to *first* create a temporary file with the
  to-be-written content, then *atomically* moving that to the
  destination.  I'm not sure what's the canonical source for this, but
  [this blog post](https://rcrowley.org/2010/01/06/things-unix-can-do-atomically.html)
  is a nice start.  The `set_data` method is particularly bad in that
  respect.

---

Okay, so the code is almost PEP8 compatible, but there's still a lot of
camel case in there.  IMO that's fine as long as it's consistent.

One note:

- Replacing `self.__class__` ... that works?  Even if it did that looks
  extremely fishy,
  c.f. [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13280680/how-dangerous-is-setting-self-class-to-something-else)
  for example.  I share the sentiment that a different mechanism would
  be better - if I see `...File()` as a constructor call I *definitely*
  don't expect a subclass of that to be the object in question.  Not
  doing "clever" things will save people minutes to hours of debugging
  time, and this is definitely too clever.  Just replace it with a
  regular function like `with livejson.mapped("test.json") as f:` or so
  and make it clear that you get a `File` subclass as a result would be
  enough for me.

Comment: hmm, I read that SO post, but it doesn't seem like many of those points apply to my case. It works fine in [my unit tests](http://bit.ly/29uETUU), which [cover 100% of my code](http://bit.ly/29gaq7y). Can you think of a scenario in my specific case when this might make debugging harder or confuse users? I feel like for my specific case, in which the class is replaced *immediately*, before the user can do anything with the class, it's roughly equivalent to a factory function. Could you elaborate on some downsides for my specific case? Otherwise, I agree completely with you, thanks a lot :D

Comment: Yes, I get your point and yes it's roughly equivalent; the coverage and testing is really great btw., so then I'd maybe downgrade it and say "if you document this behaviour clearly" it should be fine.